# alternatives to diskutil to unmount

Tags: macos, filesystems, mount

When I run  `diskutil list`, it shows that, in addition to the HD already mounted on my Mac OS, I have another mount on `/dev/disk2`, which I mounted with a project name restic that uses fuse filesystem.  When I run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` it says `Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful` but when I run `diskutil list` it shows the same mount on `/dev/disk2`. In other words, the unmount doesn't appear to have been successful. Is there another way to ensure that this disk image is unmounted?

```
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            FUSE for macOS         +16.8 MB    disk2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `diskutil eject /dev/disk2` (if it's a disk image, you can also use `hdiutil detach /dev/disk2`). There are two steps to mounting a disk image: attaching the image to a /dev entry, and mounting the volumes provided by that /dev entry. `diskutil unmountDisk` removes the mount, but leaves the /dev entry. Also, when you use `diskutil list`, that's showing attached devices, not mounted volumes; to see mounted volumes, use `mount`.